# Assign Role to User with WordPress REST API

Tags: wordpress, rest, wordpress-rest-api

I want to add user with the WordPress REST API. Each time I do, a default role of SUBSCRIBER is added to that user. No matter which role I include in my post request, it still assigns the SUBSCRIBER role.

Here is my JSON Post request:

```
    {
    "username" : "Paule",
    "first_name" : "Paul",
    "last_name" : "Ibukwe",
    "email" : "david.george@dugenterprise.com",
    "password" : "LoremIpsum123",
    "roles" : ["Candidate"]
}
```

Comment: Is role "Candidate" already present in your wordpress?

Comment: @Dmitry yes, it is

Comment: could you solve this? Got the same Problem using the latest REST API.